# Developer options suddenly disappeared

Tags: developer-options, android-studio

At the same time, the developer options suddenly disappeared on all the android devices that I used to test. I didn't do a reset or anything. Not even turning off all these devices. Why did it happen? am i hacked? maybe there are people who want to prevent me from completing the application that I made by making me confused because suddenly logcat can't connect, ON ALL ANDROID DEVICES I USE..

Comment: Please mention the device models and Android versions, and if the devices are managed by the company or not. Otherwise, we can't really help.

Comment: i use xiaomi 9a(android 10) and vivo v3(android lolipop). This two device lost developer option in setting at the same time. I do that click click thing on this two device to get that "you're a developer now" text and it show up again. I'm not shutting down this two device since the last test before i lost the developer option. It weird right?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings->~About this device~->(scroll down)Build number.
Click on it.

If it says: nothing,
try clicking on it seven times, to become developer again.
If it says: “you are already developer”,
this means the developer options should be enabled, try to find them via the settings search function.\

I do only know very little about hacking, but it seams very unlikely that someone disables developer options during an attack.
Maybe your app trigger something, or your rom does not allow you to install self build apps.(*sometimes devices, which where given to you by schools have such options disabled*)

Comment: yeah.. its weird. i just use logcat as usual and then i cant connect because developer option disabled. I activate it again by doing that click click thing till i got “you are already developer”. i use vivo v3(android lolipop) and xiaomi 9a(android 10), two different phone from different brand and different operation system. Is that even possible to disable developer option after you unlock it?